# Converting PHP site to Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla-extensions

I have a large complex web site currently implemented using PHP and MySQL. 
Some of the pages (about, contact us, etc) are largely static, but need to be updated from time to time. I'd like these updates to be able to be done by non technical admins, so I'm migrating the site to Joomla CMS. I've created a Joomla template to reproduce the banners, styling etc of my existing web site and have successfully reproduced the static pages by cutting and pasting into Joomla articles.

I'm now trying to embed my existing dyanamic php pages into the Joomla framework. I assume that I need to convert them into one or more Joomla components? I realize that I'll need to strip out the php code that currently generates banners, menus, etc, but I don't want to make major changes to these php pages, i.e. I don't want to re-implement them to follow an MVC pattern. I'm looking for a simple Joomla 3.2 hello world component tutorial. The tutorials that I've found are either too complex (i.e. MVC) or they're "too simple". By too simple I mean the component is not listed when I select Menu Item Type within the Menu Manager. Can anyone point me to any documentation that explains the minimal config that I need to include in a custom Joomla 3.2 component in order for the component to be listed when selecting Menu Item Type?

Also, should I create one big custom component to wrap my existing PHP application containing multiple pages("views"?)? Conceptually there the system could be considered as about 3 sub-systems, but there is some overlap between the MySQL tables used in these different sub-systems.

I don't need the implementation to be portable, i.e. I'm not trying to create a reusable component that others could use, I just need it to work on my site, using the least amount of work possible.

Thanks, Wayne.

Answer (score 1):

I hope to clarify a bit and give you way out.

In response to your comment on @user3057084, the power of Joomla and its flexibility comes from it being MVC! If you want to wrap your existing code with little modifications, Wordpress will let you do all kind of nasty things! Nasty in the sense of mixing logic with data, i.e. copying and pasting your code and getting it to work quickly.

Joomla coding standards require that you separate models from views.  And that you understand how the Joomla MVC implementation works.  It will take longer, but you'll learn a useful skill that can and should be applied if you want to write portable maintainable code following [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Now about the way out.

Nothing keeps you from putting your raw php code in a Joomla view, including the database access.  It's really ugly and I feel bad even suggesting this, but if it can be a small step towards using a great framework, then the end justifies the means.

The absolute easiest way for you in Joomla would be to create a template override (which you'll do from the admin with a few clicks in the template manager), then throw your code in, and it will run.  Then, a little bit at a time, you might learn to separate the parsing of the input in the controller, store / retrieve the data in a model, and leave just the markup in the view.

But are you absolutely sure you need to code for this? There are thousands of (free) extensions [out there](http://extensions.joomla.org) that might do the job for you with no coding and little configuration, leaving you just a data migration to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at Wordpress yet? In my experience, non-technical people find it easier to administer a wordpress website in comparison to a Joomla website. 
When it comes to the menu structures,themes and contact forms and blogs - Wordpress takes the cake.

It would be worth your while to check it out? It might save you hours of frustration?

Comment: I've not used Wordpress, but I am familiar with it. If my whole web site was static and my primary concern was making it simpler for the admins then I'd choose Wordpress. Wordpress has a reputation for being easier to use, but less powerful and flexible.